# Using C# to parse a SOAP Response

Tags: c#, soap

I am trying to get the values for faultcode, faultstring, and OrderNumber from the SOAP below

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Body>
        <faultcode>1234</faultcode> 
        <faultstring>SaveOrder:SetrsOrderMain:Cannot change OrderDate if GLPeriod is closed, new OrderDate is 3/2/2010:Ln:1053</faultstring>               
        <detail>
           <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
           <SOAP:Body UserGUID="test">
           <m:SaveOrder xmlns:m="http://www.test.com/software/schema/" UserGUID="test">
                <Order OrderNumber="1234-1234-123" Caller="" OrderStatus="A" xmlns="http://www.test.com/software/schema/">
```

Here is my code in C#

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XMLexample.xml"));

var errorDetail = new EcourierErrorDetail
{
   FaultCode = from fc in doc.Descendants("faultcode")
               select fc.Value,
   FaultString = from fs in c.Descendants("faultstring")
                 select fs.Value,
   OrderNumber = from o in    
                 doc.Descendants("detail").Elements("Order").Attributes("OrderNumber")
                 select o.Value
};
return errorDetail;
```

I am able to get the values for both faultcode and faultstring but not the OrderNumber. I am getting "Enumeration yielded no results." Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you're ignoring the XML namespace when selecting:

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   .....
   <m:SaveOrder xmlns:m="http://www.test.com/software/schema/" UserGUID="test">
     <Order OrderNumber="1234-1234-123" Caller="" OrderStatus="A" xmlns="http://www.test.com/software/schema/">
```

The `<Order>` tag is inside the `<m:SaveOrder>` tag which uses the XML namespace prefixed by the `m:` prefix.

Also, you're trying to select the "detail" and then you skip to the "Order" node directly (using `.Elements()`) - you missed the `<m:SaveOrder>` node in between.

You need to take that into account when selecting:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XMLexample.xml"));

XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.test.com/software/schema/";

var orderNode = doc.Descendants(xmlns + "SaveOrder").Elements(xmlns + "Order");

var value = from o in orderNode.Attributes("OrderNumber")
            select o.Value;
```

Does that give you a result??

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution could be using System.Xml.XPath. [Here is where I found the example](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1076614/How-to-read-soap-response-in-csharp#answer2)

This is how to use it in this case:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(result);

XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);

xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("m", "http://www.test.com/software/schema/");

var orderNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//m:Order", xmlnsManager);
var value = orderNode.Attributes["OrderNumber"].Value;
```

Comment: This line seems unnecessary: xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");