# Parsing a SOAP Response with C#

Tags: c#, soap, response

I've been trying to use the data from an API but I have not been able to read the XML Response from it.

It cames in the form:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAPSDK1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAPSDK2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAPSDK3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <SOAPSDK4:GetStoreProductsResponse xmlns:SOAPSDK4="http://www.externalwebservice.com/message/">
                <StoreProducts>
                    <StoreID></StoreID>
                    <Products></Products>
                </StoreProducts>
            </SOAPSDK4:GetStoreProductsResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And what I need is what is inside *Products* (for now).

I was trying to use [Using C# to parse a SOAP Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876012/) (and others to not flood this) without results.

My code:

```
    XDocument tst = XDocument.Load("Response.xml");
    XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    var tstr = from result in tst.Descendants(xmlns + "StoreProducts") select result.Element("Products").Value;
```

I am almost sure that I am missing something basic.

Any clue will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876012/using-c-to-parse-a-soap-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XML `StoreProducts` is not within an XML namespace, just do :

```
var tstr = from result in tst.Descendants("StoreProducts") 
           select result.Element("Products").Value;
```

The example code you gave would have been successful if the inner XML looked like this:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:StoreProducts>
    <StoreID></StoreID>
    <Products></Products>
  </SOAP-ENV:StoreProducts>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to parse XML ?
.NET is very efficient to handle SOAP using c# proxy.

Have you looked to svcutil.exe to generate a proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need it to read the xml sent in the post request

```
        // read the raw request
        Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string xmlPayload = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlPayload);

        XNamespace xmlns = "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com";
        item.sfId = doc.Descendants(xmlns + "Id").First().Value;
        item.AccountId = doc.Descendants(xmlns + "AccountId").First().Value;
        item.FirstName = doc.Descendants(xmlns + "FirstName").First().Value;
        item.LastName = doc.Descendants(xmlns + "LastName").First().Value;
        item.XmlPayload = xmlPayload;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get XML response ( you may skip this step )

```
string strXml; 
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))     {
    strXml = rd.ReadToEnd(); 
}
```

In order to extract Products field from the response string (strXml)

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<Products>(.*?)</Products>");
var regMatch = regex.Match(strXml);
string strProductValue = regMatch.Groups[1].ToString();
```