# Parse the SOAP response to get the desired value

Tags: c#, soap

How do I parse the following to get Value1 and Value2

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:productResponse xmlns:ns1="http://mysite.com/">
            <return xmlns:ns2="http://mysite.com/">
                <Value1>12</businessBankingInd>
                <Value2>36</businessTypeId>             
            </return>
        </ns1:productResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to convert such SOAP message to XML style, then just using `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876012/using-c-sharp-to-parse-a-soap-response) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201822/read-soap-message-using-c-sharp) links. I think they are the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wsdl or xsd you can generate C# classes based on the xml using svcutil.exe or xsd.exe or by adding a service reference in Visual Studio.

You would then deserialize the message using XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer (depends on options used to generate the objects).

After that you're just working with plain old C# objects.

Of course, if you use WCF a lot of this is taken care of for you.