# How to read soap response in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Soap Respose as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns="http://example.com/SystemIntegration">
            <FirstName>@FirstName</FirstName>
            <LastName>@LastName</LastName>
        </LoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to read it as:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(strReturnStatus);
List<XElement> result = doc.Elements("LoginResponse").ToList();
for (int intc = 0; intc <= result.Count - 1; intc++)
{
    strResponseCode = result[intc].Element("FirstName").Value.ToString();
    strResponseText = result[intc].Element("LastName").Value.ToString();
}
```

But it returning `null` result.

How to read above respose in `asp.net c#`??

Comment: It's a matter of namespace specification. Refer to the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12201822/952310

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing is to create a proxy class for your service.

You can do that using the ['Add Service Reference' option in Visual Studi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)o. Enter the URL of the service, and Visual Studio will generate the source code for you.

From that point you can access the service using C# code. No need to manually extract the payload of the SOAP message.

Note if you are the implementator of the service: ASMX webservices are deprecated for a long time already. If you can, use WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Use Descendants() method in XDocumentobject to navigate through XML nodes to get elements, you can follow steps provided in this post [Using C# to parse a SOAP Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876012/using-c-sharp-to-parse-a-soap-response?lq=1)