# How To Convert XMl Response To Data Table

Tags: c#, vb.net

I Am Trying To Convert Xml Response As String In The Following Configuration - To data Table

```
{
"message": "The response is:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:fnx1="http://www" xmlns:rob="http://" xmlns:="http://www" xmlns:soapenv="http:/" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <:RequestResponseServiceResponse>
        <rob:RobotGeneralDBQueryOut>
            <QueryResult>
                <row>
                    <column>
                        <name>KOD_ZEHUT</name>
                        <value>f</value>
                    </column>
                    <column>
                        <name>MIS_ZEHUT</name>
                        <value></value>
                    </column>
                    <column>
                        <name>SUG_HAFRASHA</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </column>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <column>
                        <name>KOD_ZEHUT</name>
                        <value>f</value>
                    </column>
                    <column>
                        <name>MIS_ZEHUT</name>
                        <value>5432</value>
                    </column>
                    <column>
                        <name>SUG_HAFRASHA</name>
                        <value>2</value>
                    </column>
                </row>
            </QueryResult>
        </rob:RobotGeneralDBQueryOut>
        <esb:ESBServiceResponseMetadata xmlns:esb="http://www">
            <esb:ResponseStatus>Success</esb:ResponseStatus>
            <esb:ResponseCode>0</esb:ResponseCode>
            <esb:ResponseDescription/>
            <esb:InstanceWFID>702167729</esb:InstanceWFID>
        </esb:ESBServiceResponseMetadata>
    </:RequestResponseServiceResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

</soapenv:Envelope>

I Want Any "Name" That Delimited In The Column To Be The Header Of The Data Table

And Any "Value" That Delimited In The Column To Be New Row Under The Name Respectively

Can Anyone Help Me?

Tnx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using C# to parse a SOAP Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876012/using-c-sharp-to-parse-a-soap-response)

Comment: 1. extract xml from json 2. use xml library to iterate columns and values 3.fill datatable with cols and vals.

Comment: Why is a SOAP response embedded inside a JSON string in the first place? Where did this come from? You can generate a client for a SOAP service using .NET's tools (eg svcutil) from the service's WSDL or XSD documents and get back the deserialized data directly. You could even right click on your project, select `Add Service Reference`, pass the service's URL and let the wizard generate the client classes and DTOs